# how to make login session never expired with database?

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

i see many tutorials and document about making session never expired using cookie. but all tutorial using static variable that make the logic is so different. my login site have 3 page :

1. `index.php` (login from this page)
2. `proses.php` (to process login)
3. `home.php` (page after login)

i'll explain my problem in every page. Firs, in `index.php`i want to remove the static variable, because i want to use dynamic database with mysqli. how can i do that?

```
  <?php
    session_start();
//static variable
    $user = 'vincy';
    $pass = md5('jokam354');
    //check session
    if(isset($_COOKIE['login']))
    {
       if ($_COOKIE['login'] == $user)
       {
          $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;

          header('location: ./home.php');
          exit();
       }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Login Remember Me</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <form action="proses.php" method="post">
             <p><label for="username">Username :</label> <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
             <p><label for="password">Password :</label> <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
             <p><label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="true" checked="checked" /> Remember Me</label></p>
             <p>
                <button type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
                <button type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
             </p>
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

`proses.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
//static variable
if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        echo 'enter username';
    } else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        echo 'enter password';
    } else {
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    }
//check login
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "reme");
   $sql = "Select * from members where member_name = '" . $username . "' and member_password = '" . $password . "'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
   //set session
   $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;

   //check remember me
   if (isset($_POST['remember']))
   {
      $time = time();
      //set cookie
      setcookie('login', $username, $time + 3600);
   }
   //redirect to home page
   header('location:./home.php');
   exit();
} else {
   header('location:./index.php');
}
?>
```

syntax `$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` in `proses.php` is not working, i get `Undefined index: member_email in C:\xampp\htdocs\remember5c\home.php on line 17` after i close the browser

`home.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
//check session
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
   header('location:./index.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Home Remember Me</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h5>Welcome, your email is <?php echo $_SESSION['member_email'];?></h5>
      <p><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

this is the table :
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVqyl.png)
Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: thanks for warning abaout SQLI but this code is only my exercise to make login page.

Comment: You should start by getting into good habits, then you'll do it automatically in future. And even if it's just an exercise, a login page (of all things) is no good if it's not secure. If I had set this exercise for a class, someone submitting to me a login page with basic security problems would not get a good mark.

Comment: Anyway you should address the remarks in symcbean's answer about what is in your table. We don't know if you even have a field called "member_email" or not.

Comment: okey thanks but can you solved my problem beside that

Comment: See my last comment. We don't have enough info to answer definitively. We have to assume that your query does not set the fields in the SESSION in the way you are expecting, but we cannot prove it. It would be better to set the SESSION fields individually anyway, then you don't have the risk of overwriting other SESSION variables set elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Also `if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
   header('location:./index.php');
}` - you need to write `if (!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
   header('location:./index.php');
   die();
}` otherwise the server will send the rest of your HTML to the client anyway, along with the "location" header. Browsers will ignore it and follow the location header, but search engines and other crawlers will still look at it, so you'll see your home page's content on google without anyone needing to log in.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a comment...

A "remember me" function is very different from a long persisting session. There are [various security implications](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128553/remember-me-vs-persistent-session-for-web-applications) to the latter.

You are not salting your password hashes which is insecure. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

You've not told us which line is 17 (though we can guess). You've not told us what the structure of the table is (does it have a member_email attribute). You've not added any diagnostics to your code to identify if it's the session or database which is the problem.

You are trying to set headers after outputting the body.

Comment: thanks for warning abaou SQLI but this code is only my exercise to make login page. and in line 17 in home.php i have this syntax $_SESSION['member_email']